# How to implement the preview of a custorm file type in iOS's email attachment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, email, preview

From iOS 3.2, application can be called to open specify files, lick .zip .
we try to implement an application can open the zip attachment file in iOS, it works.
But from iOS 4.0, apple provide a new file preview framework call [Quick Look Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS.pdf). The default email application will open the preview of the file default. But the quick look framework doesn't provide a method to implement the preview of custom file type. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? Right now if the file type is not support, the email will open a black preview View.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was sloved by iOS 4.1